# Translate numpy digitize function into c#

Tags: python, c#, translate, indices, binning

Digitize function return the indices of the bins to which each value in input array belongs.

Below code is from python -

```
x = np.array([0.8, 6.9, 3.5, 1.9])
bins = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0])
inds = np.digitize(x, bins)
print(inds)
array([1, 4, 3, 2])
```

How can I achieve same result using C#?

Comment: How about explain in your own words what it does (exactly), give example output, and show us what you have tried.

Comment: @TheGeneral: I think we both know that's not going to happen!

Comment: @MitchWheat yeah I may have been a tad optimistic there :)

Comment: [This documentation](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) seems to explain what `digitize` should do: For each item in `x`, this method returns an index `i` for the bin that the value of the array falls into. The index is where the value of `x` meets one of the following conditions: `bins[i-1] < x <= bins[i]` _or_ `bins[i-1] >= x > bins[i]` (depending on whether the bin values are getting larger or smaller). You just need to write code that does this in C#.

Comment: Use IronPython and import it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Digitize(double[] input, double[] source)
{
   foreach (var item in input)
      for (var index = 0; index < source.Length-1; index++)
         if (item > source[index] && item < source[index+1])
         {
            yield return index;
            break;
         }
}
```

**Test**

```
var input = new [] { 0.2, 6.4, 3.0, 1.6 };
var bins = new[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0 };

var results = Digitize(input, bins);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

**Output**

```
0, 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own digitize function which takes two arrays as parameters.

```
using System;

public class Test
{       
    static int findBinIndex(double input, double[] bins) {
        for(int i=1; i<bins.Length; i++){
           if(input < bins[i]) {
              return i;
           }
        }
        return bins.Length;
    }

    static void digitize(double[] x, double[] bins) {
        for(int i=0;i<x.Length;i++){
            System.Console.WriteLine(findBinIndex(x[i], bins));
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] x = new double[] {0.8, 6.9, 3.5, 1.9};
        double[] bins = new double[] {0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0};
        digitize(x, bins);
    }
}
```

You can also use Array.BinarySearch function to improve the execution time.